# How can I say this in one sentence: "I am bad, love me as I am"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

I actually have two questions:

1-
How can I say this in one sentence: **"I am bad, love me as I am"**? I was thinking about **"Love me the way I am bad"** or **"Love me as I am bad"** but I don't feel they are correct.

2-
I want to say everybody likes good people. Is it correct to say **"Everybody loves the good"**?

Comment: I would avoid: I am bad. Love me the way I am.

Comment: You probably should not say anything like "I am bad" unless you mean that you're a criminal, a deceiver, vicious, cruel, or have similarly undesirable character traits.  In other words, "bad" really *means* "BAD" and shouldn't be used casually as a self-description unless you are warning the person to stay away from you.

Comment: [*Joan, dearest, don't you love me, bad as I am?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=love+me+bad+as+I+am#tbm=bks&q=%22love+me+bad+as+I+am%22) Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  There's *plenty* wrong with that, though not grammatically.

Comment: What's wrong with saying what you want to say for #2? ***Everybody likes/loves/adores good people***

Comment: @MMacD: I don't see anything wrong with it *stylistically* either. What's your problem?

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  I meant content, not style.

Answer (score 3):

An idiomatic way to convey that thought would be

> *Love me, warts and all.*

The phrase [**warts and all**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/warts-and-all) can be used to allude to a person’s faults and shortcomings.

---

As for “Everybody loves the good,” that could refer to good people, or it could refer to anything good in life. If I read that sentence without any additional context, I’d assume it was talking about all that is good, not just good people: pleasant weather, the arts, world peace, unselfishness, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Love me though I'm bad. Love me even though I'm bad. Love me even if I'm bad.
2. Yes, it's correct to say that.

Comment: It may be correct, but it would also be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Another conventional expression like "warts and all" is

> "you must take me as you find me"

meaning that, to have a relationship with me, you must be satisfied with me as I am and not expect me to change to please you.

As to your second question,

> "Everyone loves the good"

is a fairly conventional expression, but much more often used as a general statement about the world, not about living beings particularly.

Answer (score 0):

> Love me despite my faults / flaws.

would be a gentler way to say it.

Your second sentence seems to have the sense of

> Always find the good in everyone / everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your original words verbatim, you can use a semicolon to separate the two phrases. "I am bad; love me as I am". While this is grammatically correct, for the purpose of dialogue it doesn't flow well. You could say "I may be bad, but love me as I am", but again, I personally don't think that it's a natural phrase. A better option could be to try phrasing it as a question, such as, "Can't you love me as I am, even though I'm bad/a terrible person?" or, "I may be bad, but can't you love me as I am?"

As for the second question, it is grammatically correct, but I share my precious sentiment about the way it flows. The phrasing is still a tad awkward. A more natural way to say it could be to replace "good" with a more descriptive adjective, such as "righteous" or, if you're looking for a more creative way, "Nice guys might finish last, but everyone still loves them"/"Everyone loves the nice guys".